# Ants and aphids - which should I fight first

Tags: pests, aphids, ants

My garden is full of ants, but I thought they are harmless and so I have been putting up with them till now.
However, yesterday I noticed that a pot plant has some aphids in it, and a lot of ants were running up and down the plant and there was a distinct ant-full path to the plant.

I found some similar questions here, but I want to ask the following: 
Should I fight the aphids or the ants first, and how?

I would like to use bio/organic/safe ways of getting rid of the pests.

Comment: When you can, could you post pictures?

Comment: (Un)Fortunately, the pests were gone when I checked again on them. The plant was sprayed with Calendula infusion and moved away from other plants. I think this also confused the ants and they left it alone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might have a case of [ants farming the aphids](http://www.ghorganics.com/page11.html).  If this is the case, tackling the aphids will not likely be productive as the ants will just replace the aphids.  I suspect you will need to attack the ant nest directly.  The suggestion I thought would work best from the above link was pouring boiling chili water down the nest.

Comment: Yes, I think the ants were farming the aphids - they were of the green winged type. I was thinking of using natural repellents for the ants. Actually, I have put some cinnamon sticks and citrus peels around the flower pots, as they are supposed to repel ants.

Answer (score 8):

A teaspoon of dish soap mixed with a quart of water and sprayed on will knock down the population of aphids and kill some ants.  Leave it on a minute or two and give the plant a good wash down afterwards with water.  (This is in case it is a plant with delicate leaves like lettuce or the mixture has too much soap and the fatty acids burn the leaves.)

Comment: The infested flower is Petunia, as far as I know Petunias have a weakness for aphids.

Answer (score 5):

Use neem oil or soapy water/insecticidal soap for the aphids. Most species of ants are slightly beneficial, except when they are running a protection racket on some aphids.

Comment: I have never before heard of neem oil, but after visiting this page http://www.discoverneem.com I think I'll give it a try. Not sure if it is sold here in Bulgaria, I may have to order it online. Do you know of some reputable sellers of neem oil?

Comment: In the US, it typically is sold as a treatment for roses, etc. there is usually a dusty shelf at the home improvement store that has "organic" pest and weed control stuff.